# How to get the difference between a file in a git repository's 1st commit to now?

Tags: bash, git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am working on a project that needs to check whether a file was kept the same way, and not tampered with. As part of its tests, in `.gitlab-ci.yml`, I was planning to inspect the changes from the 1st commit to now, to see whether it is changed, and if it is, then return 0 otherwise return 1.

I brainstormed around the following commands to help me reach there:

```bash
script:
- git diff-index --quiet HEAD file.java
- if [ $? == 0 ]; then return 0; else return 1; fi
```

Only thing missing is how I join them together to be able to find whether the file was changed from 1st commit to now (Note: I need to exclude the first commit, where the file was added (initial commit of the repository), and see the diff in the file from that time).

Comment: I didn't know `git diff-index` so far. Why not simply `git diff -q`? (Apparently it's `--quiet`, not `-q`: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff/en#Documentation/git-diff.txt---quiet)

Comment: If you want to prevent tampering to the CI configuration, there are better ways to achieve this. Consider also that git history can be rewritten, so this is unlikely to prevent even casual attempts at tampering. Instead, you can use the project settings to [specify a configuration file in a another project](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#specify-a-custom-cicd-configuration-file). Then any `.gitlab-ci.yml` in the project is ignored and your remote configuration is used instead -- it can be a CI yaml file in a project only you have permissions to edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check whether the file's current digest (e.g. SHA256) matches the original.

```
good_sha256="1ed9dc25920c77b19f5a12c5ab19c697f3c106febc4e3217059d193632b514fe  
.gitlab-ci.yml"

[ "$(sha256sum .gitlab-ci.yml)" != "$good_sha256" ] || echo altered
```

Comment: This also works better since git history can be rewritten.

Comment: And that is the SHA for the very first commit? Can it change from repo to repo?

Comment: It could change from repo to repo - each SHA is based on the content of the commit. You can use `git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD` to find the specific SHA of the initial commit for your repo, but otherwise this answer is a good one.

Comment: @therealvirtuoso The `good_sha256` has nothing to do with git.  It's the SHA-256 digest of whatever version of the file that you'd like to preserve in that state, and warn if it changes. It could be the 17th commit to the file. You happen to like the 17th commit and so you take its hash and validate it from then on. If someone wants to tamper with the file, they have to change the hash.  This will work better if the validation script and the file are not in the same repo. You control the script (the adversary cannot tamper with your `good_sha256`).